# System Settings stopped working 19.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, 19.04, system-settings

Out of nowhere, system settings stopped working.

Already tried:

```
$ sudo apt remove gnome-control-center 
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

What I was doing before that:

1. Installed `Pop_Os` Theme via `ppa` from their official repository
2. Changed login screen background on both:

```
$ sudo atom /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
$ sudo atom /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css
$ sudo atom /usr/share/themes/Pop-dark-slim/gnome-shell
```

to

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background-image: url(file:///home/jean/Pictures/Minimalist.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }
```

Comment: what is the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

Comment: There are 3 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0          /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/pop.css                20        auto mode
  1          /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css   15        manual mode
  2          /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css        10        manual mode
  3          /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/pop.css                20        manual mode

Comment: the * file is the one responsible for login screen. so pop.css file..

Comment: Adding software from the “Pop!_OS PPA” isn't something I'd do. Maybe you can get back to normal using `ppa-purge`.

Comment: Can you try by logging in with another (preferably newly created) user?

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP, that solved one of the problem haha.

Comment: @DKBose I just did sudo apt remove pop-theme && sudo apt autoremove and reinstalled gnome-control-center but still nothing

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I'm not sure trying with a new user would help because software versions have been changed at the system level. That's why I suggested using `ppa-purge` to get rid of all the versions installed via the ppa and to install the default versions.

Comment: Reinstalled and it's working. Now i'm even afraid to add the system76's ppa and add pop-icon-theme instead of pop-theme